# does cygwin expect linux-like paths or windows-like paths

Tags: shell, batch-file, cygwin

I'm having some trouble working on cygwin.

I have a couple of questions here

1. Say my batch script which I converted to a shell script to work on
   cygwin takes two command line arguments which initially were

   ```
   mybatchfile.bat -i "C:\Users\astro\panam\input" -o "C:\Users\astro\panam\output"
   ```

   When I pass these parameters to a shell script, do I still give the
   above command line arguments, or, do I give cygwin paths such as

   ```
   myscript.sh -i /cygdrive/c/users/astro/panam/input -o /cygdrive/c/users/astro/panam/output
   ```
2. Say, I am hardcoding a couple of paths inside my batch file/script,
   should these be windows-like paths such as
   `C:\Users\astro\panam\somepath`, or should these be cygwin paths such
   as `/cygdrive/c/users/astro/panam/somepath`
3. Say, my shell script looks as follows

   ```
   path1="C:\\Users\\astro\\panam\\Doppler\\Workspace"
   path=$path1"\\test.java"
   echo $path
   ```

   Upon executing the script, this is what I get

   ```
   PepperBoy@PepperBoy-Inspiron-3542:~$ sh changepath.sh 
   C:\Usersstro\panam\Doppler\Workspace    est.java
   ```

   As a result, none of my paths work.

Comment: Please pay attention to the information about tags such as [tag:shellscript] which say "Do not use this tag".  It means it!

Comment: Try it each way.  See what works.  See what doesn't.  You've already gone partway to seeing what is not working.  Examine the output and try to decipher what exactly is happening each time you escape something.   FWIW, your last script works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Cygwin 1.7.x, it only works with POSIX path names.

On the other hand, Windows can work with forward slashes as well. Using backslashes will just cause you an infinite amount of pain, as it's the shell escape character.

Cygwin has a handy utility to convert Windows path to POSIX ones and vica versa. To see what it can do:

```
man cygpath
```